# How to monitor the Azure Kubernetes Cluster resource status in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-monitoring

I am working on Azure Monitoring. I am trying to monitor whether the resource Status is ON/OFF. Recently, I created an Azure Kubernetes Service(Cluster) and started monitoring to that resource also. But,am not able to get the status of resource using Log Analytics queries, Insight Metrics etc.

How to find the kubernetes resource status?

Comment: can you clarify? you cannot turn AKS off.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I trying to do test like Availability Test for getting alert when the resource is Down condition

Comment: Are you mean the Pod resource or AKS Node resource?

Comment: @KasunRadithaRajapakse. For AKS Node resource

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for. We can use Azure Monitor Alerts to generate if the node count fails from a specific threshold as below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Actually am looking for AKS cluster resource not the AKS cluster nodes.

Comment: AKS cluster resource is an managed service by Azure so it wont get unavailable for the customers. We have to worry about only the worker nodes, master nodes are work as a managed service.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not give you a ready response to your question, I guess these articles from official **Microsoft Azure** documentation might be helpful:

[Enable monitoring of Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster already deployed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-enable-existing-clusters)

[Understand AKS cluster performance with Azure Monitor for containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-analyze)

If you intend to monitor AKS cluster resources, I fully agree with @Kasun Raditha Rajapakse, that it doesn't make much sense as they are fully managed by Azure and as a user you don't have to worry about availability of those kind of resources.